# Fitting gridview within contentplaceholder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview which is bigger than the size of my contentplaceholder. It wont fit within the contentplaceholder and whenever I try to edit the gridview, it increases in width making it extend even further. Can someone help

Answer (score 1):

check if your gridview have **Height** and **Width** property set.
if so.. delete **Height** prperty and set **Width** to "100%".

also place the gridview inside a **asp:Panel** control then set the **ScrollBars** property of the panel to "Horizontal" and **Width** property of the Panel to "100%"

Comment: thanks man, it has worked just fine. Hope this will help someone too